# Reading walmart product page with urllib doesn't work when using "user-agent" string

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, urllib2

I'm building django based website where some data is dynamically loaded using Ajax from a user specified url. For this I'm using urllib2 and later on BeautifulSoup. I came to strange thing with Walmart links. Take a look:

```
import urllib2
url_to_parse = 'http://www.walmart.com/ip/JVC-HARX300-High-Quality-Full-Size-Headphone/13241375'

# 1 - read the url without user-agent string
opened_url = urllib2.urlopen(url_to_parse)
print len(opened_url.read())
# prints 309316

# 2 - read the url wit user-agent string
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0' }
req = urllib2.Request(url_to_parse, '', headers)
opened_url = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print len(opened_url.read())
# prints 0
```

My question is why on #2 a zero is printed? I use the user-agent method to deal with other websites (like amazon).
Wget is able to get the page content with no problems btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not the User-Agent, it is your `data` parameter.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request):

> *data* may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server,
>   or `None` if no such data is needed.

It seems WalMart does not like your empty string. Change your call to this:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url_to_parse, None, headers)
```

Now both ways print the same value.